# adding an id to the_post_thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm attempting to use the 'feature image' feature of Wordpress to make a full screen background, that resizes to fit the browser window using jQuery

The bit I'm stuck on is adding a custom id (#bgimg) to the code generated by this:

```
<div class="background"><?php the_post_thumbnail (array(1024,768));?></div>
```

The image generated needs to have specific id tag in it, eg...

```
<img id="bgimg" src="wordpress/generated/etc.jpg">
```

So that the jQuery plugin, can hook on to it, and scale it to fit the browser window. I know the jQuery works (as I've used it in other projects)

Any suggestions?
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) instead. It allows you to pass in an array of attributes for the image tag that gets returned.

For example:

```
$attr = array(
    'id' => 'YOUR-UNIQUE-ID',
);

echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'thumbnail', $attr );
```

**EDIT:**

I'm dumb. [the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) also lets you do that. Try passing the same args array I outlined as the second param.